# Invalid configuration while Hadoop Yarn Resourcemanager HA

Tags: docker, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

I'm trying to set HA configuration on Hadoop Namenode and Resourcemanager.

Basically, I'm using docker containers (docker-compose) to deploy each Node and I'm working on EC2 Ubuntu 22.04.2

Of course, it is useless that deploy all containers in one EC2 instance, but I'm just studying and testing HA configurations.

For a better understanding,
[image]
it is my goal.

I made all parts of Namenode but I'm getting trouble in Resourcemanager.

according to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html#Configurations,
I made my yarn-site.xml

```xml
<!-- for Resource Manager HA Configuration -->
    <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
                <value>resourcemanager-cluster</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
                <value>rm1,rm2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
                <value>resourcemanager1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostmane.rm2</name>
                <value>resourcemanager2</value>
        </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.zk.address</name>
                <value>zookeeper-rm1:2181,zookeeper-rm2:2181,zookeeper-rm3:2181</value>
        </property>
```

I made all settings(apt-get update, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml etc...) on my own docker image from Ubuntu:22.04.02 and commit it on my EC2 by name ubuntu:hdfs-test

And part of docker-compose.yml below

```xml
  resourcemanager1:
    image: ubuntu:hdfs-test
    build:
      dockerfile: ./hadoop.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: resourcemanager1
    container_name: resourcemanager1
    networks:
      - hadoop
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
      - 8032:8032
      - 8034:8034
    tty:
      true

  resourcemanager2:
    image: ubuntu:hdfs-test
    build:
      dockerfile: ./hadoop.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: resourcemanager2
    container_name: resourcemanager2
    networks:
      - hadoop
    ports:
      - 8089:8088
      - 8033:8033
      - 8035:8035
    tty:
      true

  zoorm1:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoorm1
    container_name: zookeeper-rm1
    networks:
      - hadoop
    ports:
      - 2184:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoorm1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoorm2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoorm3:2888:3888;2181

  zoorm2:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoorm2
    container_name: zookeeper-rm2
    networks:
      - hadoop
    ports:
      - 2185:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoorm1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoorm2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoorm3:2888:3888;2181

  zoorm3:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoorm3
    container_name: zookeeper-rm3
    networks:
      - hadoop
    ports:
      - 2186:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoorm1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoorm2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoorm3:2888:3888;2181
```

Hadoop version is 3.3.0 and zookeeper version is latest(3.8.1)

Some ports(8032, 8033, 8034, 8035) is used for testing yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm1 property before.

After docker-compose, access container resourcemanager1 and type below

```bash
start-yarn.sh
```

and in logs/hadoop-root-resourcemanager-resourcemanager1.log says,

```
************************************************************/
2023-05-15 22:18:19,306 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2023-05-15 22:18:19,837 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMNMInfo: Registered RMInfo MBean
2023-05-15 22:18:19,841 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service ResourceManager failed in state INITED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Invalid configuration! yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2 or yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2 needs to be set in an HA configuration.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.throwBadConfigurationException(HAUtil.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.checkAndSetRMRPCAddress(HAUtil.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.verifyAndSetRMHAIdsList(HAUtil.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.verifyAndSetConfiguration(HAUtil.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1584)
2023-05-15 22:18:19,844 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2023-05-15 22:18:19,844 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2023-05-15 22:18:19,844 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Invalid configuration! yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2 or yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2 needs to be set in an HA configuration.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.throwBadConfigurationException(HAUtil.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.checkAndSetRMRPCAddress(HAUtil.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.verifyAndSetRMHAIdsList(HAUtil.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.verifyAndSetConfiguration(HAUtil.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1584)
2023-05-15 22:18:19,847 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at resourcemanager1/172.21.0.9
************************************************************/
```

So my core question is, what is the meaning of

```
Invalid configuration! yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2 or yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2 needs to be set in an HA configuration.
```

I think I just followed hadoop.apache.org docs... And can't get any clue after googling myself...

I omit some settings(docker-compose, hdfs-site.xml etc...) because it is too long. But if needed, I'll post it later.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to run YARN in containers? YARN runs containers itself, so you're ultimately limiting what code can actually run there.

Comment: Overall, I strongly advise against using EC2/Docker. Use EMR and forget about trying to containerize everything. That's not helping you learn Hadoop, and you'll run into more issues later

Comment: Thank you for advising! It really helped. I'm studying distributed system class at my school. And my project subject is HA of namenode and resourcemansger. My purpose is just showing promotion of standby, not real operation. It's hard to get real machines and networking multiple EC2s. So I chose docker as VM.

Comment: Networking EC2 is done out of the box within a VPC... EMR already sets up a highly available Hadoop cluster on EC2 for you... Still, using local VMs would be better than Docker, for other reasons, including cost